# Chat history lost after porting WhatsApp number to another network

Tags: whatsapp, chat

I recently ported my WhatsApp number to another network. When porting was completed I put a new SIM in my phone. And then my WhatsApp stopped working, it said you have to update WhatsApp but I checked there is no update available. So I uninstalled it and then again reinstalled it. Now all my chats are removed, they didn't even come back from the backup. What should I do? Also, my ported SIM is not activated too, will this have an effect?

Answer (score 2):

- The backup of whatsapp in Windows devices stay **local** , i.e; they get saved in sd card or in internal memory unlike Apple and Android devices, where backups go to cloud(idrive n Google drive respectively).
- Before uninstalling the whatsapp, you must check for backup(whatsapp automatically backs up the messages from time to time), then next time while reinstallig the app, it will ask if u want to restore the messages.
- and because you didn't do that, am sorry, your messages are gone.
- or you could just reinstall again and you can restore previous messages that were available before installing whatsapp. Check if you have **Whatsapp\WinPhoneBackup** folder in sd card.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the second point. Whatsapp does create automatic backups everyday. So saying a *user should have created backup while uninstalling* is not necessary. Please consider to edit it.(Any edit that disagree with the author should not made by others, so I am commenting this while I edited other typos)

Comment: it does create automatic backups , just go to settings and see for yourself when was your messages backed up, probably 3-5 hrs ago!

Comment: Glad that you agree with my point. I would be happy if you edit your answer accordingly. Your answer still says *you should create a backup* which is not required as per your comment.